# Turn times into percentage for pie chart

Tags: percentages

First time posting here so hope am in the right place.

I have a report which is a breakdown of time spent in hours/minutes for certain projects over a monthly period.  I want to show these as a pie chart.  For example, I may have:-

TASK1 - Duration 00:25

TASK2 - Duration 00:50

TASK3 - Duration 02:35

Total time is 03:50

How would I convert the three into, in this case, a three segment pie chart please?

Thanks

Craig.

Answer (score 1):

**Divide the duration of each task by the total duration:**

---

Task $1:\dfrac{0\cdot60+25}{3\cdot60+50}=\dfrac{ 5}{46}$

---

Task $2:\dfrac{0\cdot60+50}{3\cdot60+50}=\dfrac{10}{46}$

---

Task $3:\dfrac{2\cdot60+35}{3\cdot60+50}=\dfrac{31}{46}$

---

**Divide the pie-chart into $46$ equal segments, and assign:**

- $ 5$ segments for task #$1$
- $10$ segments for task #$2$
- $31$ segments for task #$3$